# How to backup a decrypted ransomware android studio projects without getting reinfected?

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a ransomware (STOP/DJVU family with .reco and .bora extensions and an online key) and had no backups so i had to pay to get my files back(please don't judge me...i know paying makes them spread wider)
I recieved a decryption tool and a key, i used them to decrypt my files.

I tried almost every Antivirus and Antimalware on the market and scanned all the projects and every suspicious file was quarantined and deleted. 
I have been advised by a friend to make backups and install a clean windows because most attackers leave a backdoor to reattack later.

The question is how to backup my Android Studio projects without worrying about a reinfection...i know i did scan all my files but there maybe something hidden that was not detected

Does pushing projects to github and deleting the original files help eliminate the problem?

Any ideas?

Second question
I have a copy of the encrypted files and the decrypted files, the tool and the keys, i would like to send them to someone who works in decrypting ransomwares, maybe this can help someone...where should i send it or to whom?

Answer (score 0):

Nehad,

I just stumbled on your post.  I have suffered the exact same attack (bora and reco), and now waiting for the top decryption agencies to provide a tool to save my data.

Did you really have a successful outcome after paying the ransom - all advice is that those of us attacked should never pay.....of course depends on the value of your data!

I suggest that you contact EmsiSoft first - they already offer a decrypt tool for offline attacks.....https://www.emsisoft.com/ransomware-decryption-tools/

Also contact Michael Gillespie - he seems to be at the forefront of anti-ransomware research....https://twitter.com/demonslay335?lang=en

Cheers.

Andy

Comment: Apparently EmsiSoft can't help - they are AntiVirus, not a Decrypter developer.

Comment: My key was an online key...i tried all the free decrypting tools online...nothing worked.

Comment: I sent Michael Gillespie the details, i hope he checks it soon...thanks Andy

Comment: Sorry forgot to answer your question. ..yes, i did get all my data back...i was so worried that they would receive the money and never contact me again but they did, i am trying to back up my data now...i should've done that before the attack 